# Actionbar with tabs with supporting versions below 11

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to implement this example in android.developer : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Adding
When i use the TabListener class :

```
TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener { }
```

The unimplemented methods (onTabSelected - onTabUnselected - onTabReselected) look like that :

```
@Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab arg0,
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

But in the example , it looks like :

```
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // User selected the already selected tab. Usually do nothing.
}
```

Why should i use android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction and not FragmentTransaction ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `appcompat_v7` (`ActionBarActivity`) to support older devices, or if you are using ActionBarSherlock to support older devices, you will need to use the fragments backport from `android-support-v4`. Its version of `FragmentTransaction` is `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction`. `android.app.FragmentTransaction` is for the native API Level 11+ version of fragments.

Answer (score 1):

Because the android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction is the version for android versions below 11 
this is why it is included in the support library.

FragmentTransaction will not work on versions below api lvl 11. But android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction will work.

Answer (score 0):

So i should use android.support.v4.FragmentTransaction to support all versions (including versions below 11) , Am i right ?
And i need also to extend android.support.v4.app.Fragment to use Fragments , Right ?